# How to test if a remote host port is accessible or not in Unix

Tags: networking, unix

In Windows, I go to command line and 'telnet  ' to check the port. How to do the same in Unix?

It seems some people using 'tcpdump port ' commands. Is this monitoring the real time traffic? Thanks.

Comment: [nmap](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/nmap)

Comment: FYI if you ever have occasion to actually send data to a remote host and/or receive a response back, Linux/Unix has `netcat` which you can use in place of `telnet` for that.

Comment: Also, and I'm sad I don't see it in the comments section here, Unix has telnet too.

Comment: Thanks everyone, all answers have been really helpful. My last question is what tool is 'tcpdump port' commands in Unix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`nmap` is a great general-purpose tool for such things and much else.

`nmap host.domain.tld` (or `nmap host` for a local machine, or `nmap <ipaddr>` to check a machine by address not name) will list what common ports are open.

`nmap 192.168.23.1-254 -p 22,80,443` will scan a range of hosts by address to see if the TCP ports usually associated with SSH, HTTP and HTTPS are open.

See `man nmap` for many more options - it is the kitchen sink of network checking tools.

You may not have nmap installed at the moment, but it is in just about all distros standard repositories. For debian or ubuntu variants `aptitude install nmap` to install it, or find it in the GUI package manager of your choice. If it isn't available easily on your system, get it and more info from http://nmap.org/

You could also just use the same `telnet` client technique that you are already familiar with as that is available too and usually installed in one of the default packages, but `nmap` is a tool worth getting to know as it can be helpful for diagnosing network issues, just checking that things are as they should be, and so on. There are also a few decent graphical front-ends to it, if you would prefer to interact with it away from the command line.

Comment: +1 `nmap` is way better than `telnet` for this task.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using bash, then the man pages state that you could write to /dev/tcp/HostNameOrIP/port. I've used this a few times and if the remote port is open, then there is no response. If the system cannot connect to the remote port, then it states the reason

```
[kevin@box ~]$ echo -n > /dev/tcp/www.yahoo.com/80
[kevin@box ~]$ nslookup www.no-such-domain.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find www.no-such-domain.com: NXDOMAIN

[kevin@box ~]$ echo -n > /dev/tcp/www.no-such-domain.com/80
-bash: www.no-such-domain.com: Name or service not known
-bash: /dev/tcp/www.no-such-domain.com/80: Invalid argument
[kevin@box ~]$ echo -n > /dev/tcp/192.168.3.3/80    #no such server on my network
-bash: connect: No route to host
-bash: /dev/tcp/192.168.3.3/80: No route to host
[kevin@box ~]$ echo -n > /dev/tcp/192.168.3.1/88    #nothing listening on port 88
-bash: connect: Connection refused
-bash: /dev/tcp/192.168.3.1/88: Connection refused
[kevin@box ~]$
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise to rely on this trick, because at least debian bash packages have this feature stripped off.

Comment: Which is why I grumble at systems whose man pages say this works, but then I get 'no such file or directory'.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `telnet` on a *nix machine, too.

Comment: +1 - there's even an SSL capable variant.

Comment: @sybreon - I was not aware of that.. who provides it?

Comment: You can download the Debian package or the source code from http://packages.debian.org/lenny/telnet-ssl

Comment: cool - I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

To test if port is accessible in Bash, you may use the following one-line command:

```
$ </dev/tcp/example.com/80 && echo Port is open || echo Port is closed
Port is open
```

To check manually, use `telnet` command (similar as on Windows).